# Install ngnix on ubuntu 20.04 using ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

Hi i am new to ansible i have to deploy nodejs12.8.4, SSL and ngnix latest to Ubuntu 20.04 server can someone guide me how to do it thank you.

this is my yml file:

```
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: install nodejs prerequisites
      apt:
        name:
          - apt-transport-https
          - gcc
          - g++
          - make
        state: present
    - name: add nodejs apt key
      apt_key:
        url: https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key
        state: present
    - name: add nodejs repository
      apt_repository:
        repo: deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x {{ ansible_lsb.codename }} main
        state: present
        update_cache: yes
    - name: install nodejs
      apt:
        name: nodejs
        state: present
```

it install nodejs 12 now i want to install nginx in same file how i add new task.

Comment: You can add `nginx` to the list of names in one of your existing apt task or add a seperate apt task for this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html. If you need a full blown nginx install with configuration and customization, see @vladimir linked role in his response.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Ansible NGINX Role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/nginxinc/nginx). See details at [Github](https://github.com/nginxinc/ansible-role-nginx).

---

> Q: "*I want to install Nginx in the same file how I add a new task?"*

A: [Include the role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role)

```yaml
    - include_role:
        name: nginx
```

[Download](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#ansible-galaxy) the role. See [Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#roles) and [Using Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles) in particular.

Comment: kindly see my question i update can u edit my yml file to install nginx

Comment: This is a [Question/Answer site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with the ultimate intent of [collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292175/what-is-the-purpose-of-stack-overflow).  There are clear [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for those who ask and those who answer. I'm not going to modify the code in your question. There might be others interested in understanding the question and potential answers.  See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).